# Jotai atom always null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jotai

I have a React Native Expo application with Jotai, but the Jotai atom is always null.

App.tsx

```
const App = () => {
  const [organisation, setOrganisation] = useAtom(organisationAtom)

  useAsyncEffect(async () => {
    const value = await read<User>("user")
    setOrganisation(value)
  }, [])

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {organisation ? <BottomTabNavigator/> : <StepNavigator/>}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.tsx:

```
export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [organisation, setOrganisation] = useAtom(organisationAtom)

  const handle = async ({data}: BarCodeEvent) => {
    const json: AttachResponse = JSON.parse(data);

    if (json.organisation == undefined || json.token == undefined)    {
      alert(i18n.t('alerts.scan.invalid'));
      return;
    }

    await write("user", json)
    setOrganisation(json)
    console.log("StepThree json " + json.token)
    console.log("StepThree org " + organisation!!.token)
  }

  return <Scanner onScanned={(data) => handle(data)}/>
}
```

state.ts

```
export const organisationAtom = atom<User|null>(null)
```

I've tried many things, but unfortunately I'm unable to make it behave differently.

PS:
The two logs log this AFTER a new startup (when the secure store is already filled):

```
StepThree json o4k7sdBG0T4H3uqvWFFSMPJMZxealYUGdUe
StepThree org o4k7sdBG0T4H3uqvWFFSMPJMZxealYUGdUe
```

And this when the application is fresh (no secure store values):

```
StepThree json o4k7sdBG0T4H3uqvWFFSMPJMZxealYUGdUe
Organisation is null (TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'organisation.token'))
```

So it seems that Jotai is reactive after a restart?